# Is every key the same thing?

Tags: theory

Have you noticed that sometimes you can recognize a song just by listening to about 3-4 notes?
*We can transpose those 3-4 notes to a different key, and I bet you would still recognize it. Even if I played them with a different instrument you would still recognize it!*
Just so long as those notes are played in the right rhythm, it is recognizable.

Isn't this because there are 7 notes in a key The **1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th, 6th 7th (8th)**, and those 7 notes are proportional to some different key... if you get what I'm trying to say.

Wouldn't this mean that every key is the same thing? That every song ever made is just a different arrangement of the **1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th, 6th 7th (8th)** (excluding jazz)

That is amazing, and it means that music has more to do with rhythm than notes.

Every key is the just the first, second, third, ect, in a higher/lower proportional tone? So this means all keys are "the same"?

Comment: I think there are 12 notes in a key, and the arrangement of them changes color of sound. Rhythm is very important and often overlooked, because it is the other half of playing. For song recognition that is just because we humans tend to pick up on melody quite quick. The melody of a tune sticks and understanding melody in song creation is quite powerful.

Comment: The Well-Tempered Clavier by some minor baroque composer might well be worth researching (and listening to).

Comment: The rhythm does not need to be identical, variations on a theme probably all have different rhythms but you can still recognise the melody it was built on

Comment: @NeilMeyer - funnily enough, it's something I do to show students how important the rhythmic pattern of a song is. I play all the right notes, in the right order, but change the note values,and chances are they *don't* recognise what the tune is - because, simply, it's *not* the same tune as original...

Comment: Also check out the Parsons code classification of melodies according to their contour. Starting with the first note, each successive note of the melody is either a Repeat of the previous note, or goes Up or Down.  http://www.musipedia.org/pc.0.html?&L=0

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of 12 EDO, where all the notes have been subtly moved by just a little, to make any tune sound just as good in any key. A couple of hundred years ago, an instrument could be tuned to sound good in one key. But try to play a piece in a different key, and it would sound slightly out of tune.

That's when it was realised that by moving the pitches very slightly, the same tune would sound pretty good when transposed to any of the 12 keys. It's called *equal temperament*.

Comment: That's so fascinating. Where can I find out more about this?

Comment: @emero - this is a good start (it's a big subject): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_temperament

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially correct, in that a song or melody played in a certain key can be transposed to any other any other key - that is, can be played starting on any note and still be recognizable - but here's the nub. When we talk about the key of a piece - for example, A major - we are talking about a collection of 7 notes (In this case, A,B,C#,D,E,F#,G#, or Do, re, mi, fa, sol, la, ti). If you start in a different key - say, C Major - you would have a scale made of different tones (C,D,E,F,G,A,B); HOWEVER, they still occupy the same place in the key (Do, re, mi, etc.), and so it's easy (when you know your scales!) to transpose keys on the fly.

But in the western musical tradition, **tempered** instruments have **12** distinct tones! A major scale, like many common used scales, is merely a **collection** of tones. Most scales - for example, the **major and minor** scales - use 7 distinct notes just like the major scale. And while you might start a scale on the same note - in this case, **A** - the specific pattern of notes you pick determines the key. **A major**, as we have seen, is comprised of a **whole** step, another **whole** step, a **half** step, **three whole** steps, and a **half** step (the last half step is between G#, or ti,  and A at the top, or Do):

**A** | A# | **B** | C | **C#** | **D** | D# | **E** | F | **F#** | G | **G#** | **A**

Do..........re..........mi....fa...........sol.........la.............ti....do

Alternatively, a **minor** scale has the pattern, **whole, half, whole, whole, half, whole, whole**:

**A** | A# | **B** | **C** | C# | **D** | D# | **E** | **F** | F# | **G** | G# | **A**

Do.........re....me..........fa..........sol....le...........te............do

Either of these scales can be transposed to different keys, and although the specific collection will change, the pattern of steps, and therefore the **solfege** (do, re, mi etc.) will not change. These patterns are called **modes**; the most common are major and minor. Although a scale or melody may start on the same note, it is not necessarily in the same key. Thus, the key is determined by two factors: the starting note (1st and 8th, or **Do**), which we call the **tonic**, and the mode, which have different names.

So what are the different modes? First think of a C major scale - no sharps or flats, all the white keys on a piano - C,D,E,F,G,A,B,(C). If we play the notes in this order starting on C it sounds like C major - we call this the **Ionian**, or major, mode. But what if we played the same collection of notes, but starting on a different note - like A for example? We get the **Aeolian**, or minor, scale. Starting on different notes will yield more exotic scales. (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Music_Theory/Modes)

If you're interested in understand more about the nature of the scales, and music theory in general, i recommend studying the **Circle of Fifths** (for reading keys/music) as well as learning **solfege**, which helps immensely with **audiating**, the process of accurately expressing what you hear in your head. Once you can hear it, you can sing it, and if you can sing it, you can play it, and if you can play it, you can retire to a cottage in Florida at the age of sixty three for some quality time with the local beach bunnies.

Comment: You mean **tonic sol-fa** to be moveable doh. **Solfege** is fixed doh - always **C** and used certainly in France and other continental countries.

Comment: And actually, trying to audiate in solfege is damned difficult compared with tonic sol-fa. I play with French musicians and they find it really easy, though.

Comment: I was indeed referring to movable do; in the U.S. (and by extension American English) this is generally what is meant by solfege, although I admit I should be a bit more careful making assumptions about my audience!From the wiki page: There are two current schools of applying solfège: 1) fixed do, where the syllables are always tied to specific pitches (e.g. "do" is always "C-natural") and 2) movable do, where the syllables are assigned to scale degrees ("do" is always the first degree of the major scale).

Comment: It's an interesting read about the two - similarities/differences/history. In my 'Oxford Companion to Music': two paragraphs are dedicated to 'solfege', while seven pages explain 'tonic sol-fa'. It would be interesting to try to explain one to someone who is used to the other! I've tried and bewilderment is the usual result.    Also - have a read of your second para., one sentence is odd.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the notes which are used that matter. Rather, it's the intervals between the notes that help distinguish and identify a melody.

So instead of thinking of a melody as a series of notes; think of it as a series of intervals. This way it doesn't matter which note you start on. If the intervals are identical then the melody will be recognizable regardless of the key you're playing in.